# How to draw a line chart like this?

Tags: graphics, pstricks, charts

From this site, I have learned how to draw fancy pie charts and bar charts.

However, I cannot find a simple way to draw a line chart like the [google's](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart). Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to draw similar line chart in LaTeX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package as a starting point. There are some more [examples](http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/all/).

Comment: Do you have data?

Comment: @HarishKumar, no, I have no special data. Any testing data is ok.

Answer (score 2):

<shameless plug>

May I suggest the paper Leyla and I wrote some time ago about inclusion of plots generated by outside programs in LaTeX?  Here is it: http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-3/tb108veytsman.pdf

</shameless plug>